# How can I improve my BF factorial code to input large numbers and output the whole result?

Tags: brainfuck

I recently began again to do some BF for fun, and today I made a factorial code, which as I know is different than a lot I found in the net. I only need five cells to compute it but unfortunately I can't input number such as for example 100.

I'd like to know, if someone has an idea, how could I do to improve *my code* to be able to do that?

*EDIT : A, B, C, D and E are the cells*

```
++++               #For example we put four in input

[->+<]             #Put A in B and A=0
[-]                #If A=0 (which is true)
>-                 #Decrease B by one
[->+>+>+<<<]       #Put B in C, D and E (at the end pointer is on B)
>                  #Move on C                                
[-<+>]             #Put C in B and C=0
<+                 #Add one in B
>>[-<<<+>>>]       #Put D in A and D=0
>                  #Pointer move on E

[                                         #While
     -                                    #E is not null
     <<<<
     [->[->+>+<<]>[-<+>]<<]>[-]>>[-<<+>>] #Do A*B and put the result in B
     >
     [-<+<<<+>>>>]                        #Put E in A and D
     <
     [->+<]                               #Then put D in E
     >                                    #pointer goes on E to test the while condition
]                                         #While end

<<<                #If E is null go back to cell B
[-<+>]             #Put B in A 
<                  #Pointer on A at the end
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

---

If you need help to visualise the code step by step [go there](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/)
The best interpreter I use is [this one](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/), you can perform BF on 32 bits and count numbers of operations. It needs more than two thousands of billion to make factorial of 19... but it is really fast.

Comment: Supporting numbers up to 100 have nothing to do with your code specifically; it just depends on your interpreter, and the size of integer it supports. If you would for example use a python interpreter, your code would produce results even for very high factorials; if you use a 32bit one, you will be limited, unless you implement some way to store bigints in brainfuck, and implement all of the arithmetics this requires, and I suspect the code to do that will overflow the character limit of answers here. For short - **use interpreter that supports BigInts**.

Comment: >++++++++++>>>+>+[>>>+[-[<<<<<[+<<<<<]>>[[-]>[<<+>+>-]<[>+<-]<[>+<-[>+<-[>
+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>[-]>>>>+>+<<<<<<-[>+<-]]]]]]]]]]]>[<+>-
]+>>>>>]<<<<<[<<<<<]>>>>>>>[>>>>>]++[-<<<<<]>>>>>>-]+>>>>>]<[>++<-]<<<<[<[
>+<-]<<<<]>>[->[-]++++++[<++++++++>-]>>>>]<<<<<[<[>+>+<<-]>.<<<<<]>.>>>>] with 8bits you can find all factorial you want.. @UrielEli

Comment: How does this work? Does it compute it or just print factorials (it uses ascii for printing numbers, while you use the memory as the result)

Comment: @UrielEli I guess yes but not sure, just I'd like to do mine not choose what someone else did. ^^

Comment: That's what I'm saying, thats the issue with your algo. You can also use genetics algorithms to generate BF code, but that would miss all the fun.

Answer (score -3):

well you would need to implement some sort of bigint functionality. How to do so will not fit in an answer here (read: i don't know), considering that the only unbounded data structure that's easy to implement in bf is a single stack placed after any other cells you might want to use.

You could implement, for example, 16 bit operations in terms of multiple 8 bit operations (likewise 32 bit in terms of 16 and so on) but factorials grow really really fast and not even a 64 bit value can hold 100! (which is 3.1e158, which means you would need at least 529 bits to represent)

Good luck implementing bigints in BF